# Updating mongo SSL-Cerificates in Mongo ReplicaSet

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-replica-set

I have mongo Replica Set with 2 Mongo Nodes and 1 Arbiter and I just need to extend expiration date for mongo SSL certificates. I won't change the names of keys and key attributes like CN, O and etc. The question is should I then restart all mongo services or not ?

Comment: idk exactly what you are doing, but you can shut one down, then up; then a second node down, and up...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know MongoDB does not presently support online certificate rotation.

Meaning, you need to restart each node in sequence after you change the certificates.